Electrostatics: Electric Potential of Earth
I have a very basic question which is:  Why we consider the potential of Earth to be zero?
Generally in physics we consider the electric potential at infinity to be zero. But while reading about conductors I found out this statement.
But again in my class my physics teacher told me that actually Earth has negative potential. But he didn't clearly explain it to me.
It would be of great help if one clarifies my doubt.

Does this answer your question? Why the electric potential of Earth is zero?

But it doesn't explain why earth has a negative electric potential?

It's my understanding the Earth overall is electrically neutral, though the crust may be negative and the core positive, though there seems to be disagreement.

The earth has negative charge, and so an static electric field of about 100 V/m. But this has nothing to do with using earth potential as 0 . You can use any conducting thing  as zero potential , in a car it is the metallic surface,  even a line which could have 1000V relativ to earth can be declared as 0 potential.
